# Can't access struct outside of function, out of scope

Tags: swift

**EDITED**  to write the whole code.
What I'm trying to solve is that once I get the data from Firebase, it displays the same data over and over (the amount of the array, in this case 0, 1, 2). The data is being retrieved correctly.

[image]

It seems to not be populating the array correctly when I update it on the local variable so I can use it when displaying the posts in the table view. This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import Foundation

class StylerSalonHomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView:UITableView!
    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
            layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        }

        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        observe()

        tableView.reloadData()

    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
             return 180
     }



    @IBAction func handleLogout(_ target: UIBarButtonItem) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    func observe() {
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "post")

                postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                    var tempPosts = [Post]()

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                            let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                            let first_name = data["Author"] as? String,
                            let postTitle = data["title"] as? String,
                            let postDescription = data["description"] as? String,
                            let postUrl = data["postUrl"] as? String,
                            let postAddress = data["Address"] as? String,
                            let url = URL(string:postUrl)
                        {
                            let post = Post(author: first_name, postTitle: postTitle, postDescription: postDescription, postUrl: url, postAddress: postAddress)
                            tempPosts.append(post)

                        }
                    }

                    self.posts = tempPosts

                    // HERE IT WORKS
                    print(self.posts[0].postTitle , " 0")
                    print(self.posts[1].postTitle , " 1")

                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        // HERE IT DOESN'T WORK
        print(self.posts[0].postTitle , " 0")
    }


    func getDateFromTimeStamp(timestamp : Double) -> String {
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" //Specify your format that you want
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        return strDate
    }

}
```

The function that I have to access my data and store it into the `var posts = [Post]()` is observe() but if you notice the comments there, I can't call the array outside of that function, could that be the problem? When I do, it says: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

I believe that the error is accessing the data outside of `postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it displays the same data over and over (the amount of the array, in this case 0, 1, 2)" because on the screenshot they cells have different data (other than the image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing all your code I can't be totally sure, but I think this is a timing issue.

Until you run `observe()` you won't have any observer on the database, and then it won't populate any data in the `updatePosts.posts` array until (1) there is a database change that triggers a snapshot and (2) the closure completes processing the snapshot.

Where  are you calling `observe()`? Is it before `viewDidLoad` runs and tries to print out the array contents?  And are you confident that a snapshot will be received and processed by the time `viewDidLoad` runs?  Otherwise in `viewDidLoad` you are trying to index items in the `posts` array that don't yet exist, which is why you are getting `index out of range` errors.

What are you trying to achieve in `viewDidLoad` that means you need to access the `posts` array as there might be another approach that avoids this issue?

Comment: let me update the question with some screenshots so it's better understood

Comment: I added more details, I hope it's useful :)

Comment: OK, but I still think it's the same issue.  Where you write `//HERE IT DOESN'T WORK` I wouldn't expect it to work.  In the block of code following `postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in ` you create a closure that you register with the firebase service so that it can use it when there is a change in the data.  You are only **registering** the code at this point, not executing it.  Once the code has been registered you app will then proceed to the next line (outside of the closure) where it tries to print it.  But at this point the firebase closure won't have run ...

Comment: ... (contd). (remember you've only registered it, not run it) so there will be no data for it to print.  Then at some later point the closure will run and store it's data in in the array and then reload the tableView (if the viewcontroller still exists).  Having said all that though, I don't think that is why you are getting duplicate images in your tableView!